# How to set environment variables on Meteor's remote server

Tags: meteor, environment-variables

Setting an environment variable on the localhost is done using `export`.

e.g. `export PORT=80`

My Question is how to set an environment var for the **remote** meteor server.
I am using Meteor's free hosting service and deploy using `meteor deploy appname`, and therefore have no ssh access to the remote command line.

I'd like to set `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS` to true.
I've looked at the list of possible meteor commands and haven't found one which relates to setting env vars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it the same way when you run your server e.g, you don't have to use `export` you can just put the environment variables in the line you use to start meteor.

```
PORT=80 node main.js
```

or if you use forever

```
PORT=80 forever start main.js
```

or even with `meteor`

```
DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=TRUE meteor
```

I'm a bit confused about your setup, by remote meteor server you mean a production environment? You shouldn't use the `meteor` command in production as it is not optimized this way and performance would be very significantly affected.

Meteor gets the environment variables using `process` so whatever you use to start the process you can pass the environment variables to it using the typical terminal/bash/shell/ssh that you used to start the process up.

Comment: I am using Meteor's free hosting service and deploy using `meteor deploy appname`. Therefore I don't have ssh access to the command line

Comment: With meteor deploy only certain variables can be changed such as `MAIL_URL` using `process.env.MAIL_URL = '..'` but stuff like the port and disable_websockets can't be changed because they're used to start the app up. You would have to use your own hosting environment to change these.