# Disable websockets when deploying to subdomain.meteor.com

Tags: meteor

What is the right way to disable websockets when deploying an app on Meteor's own infrastructure (i.e. when deploying to myapp.meteor.com)?

When running locally I can just set DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS env var, but obviously this doesn't work when deploying. Is there an equivalent Meteor.settings config field?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. I found this on another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088392/how-to-set-environment-variables-on-meteors-remote-server)
"With meteor deploy only certain variables can be changed such as MAIL_URL using process.env.MAIL_URL = '..' but stuff like the port and disable_websockets can't be changed because they're used to start the app up. You would have to use your own hosting environment to change these." 

So can it be done?